# How to properly ignore files from git using .gitignore file?

Tags: git, git-bash, gitignore

My assignment is requiring me to ignore two folders from git along with their contents. I have created a `.gitignore.txt` file and typed in the folders' names in the file:

[image]

I have also tried the above with a /* at end of file names and without any forward slash or asterisk at all. However, git seems to still recognize these folders. Here is the result I receive each time I use `git status` command in git-bash.

[image]

git is still recognizing these folders since they are within the untracked files, correct? What do I need to do to have git ignore the folders completely?

Comment: Your gitignore file has the extension .txt.  it should be just .gitignore

Comment: Thanks, Windows. (You should turn off "hide file extensions" in case you haven't)

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks for the idea of unhiding file extensions! Should make things easier

Comment: Also, there was a typo in my Notepad picture above. all fixed now and working! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a file called `.gitignore.txt`, which is not special to Git in any way.  The file must be called exactly `.gitignore`, with no extension.

Many Windows programs automatically append a file extension, and Notepad is no different.  You're going to be a little better off using a slightly more capable text editor.  There are many; any one is fine.

In the mean time, you can quit Notepad, then do `mv .gitignore.txt .gitignore` and things should work.

Comment: This worked great! Hadn't realized that the .txt extension must not be included. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong filename - it's supposed to be just `.gitignore`, without an extension, and **not** `.gitignore.txt`.